# Android : ActionBar menu item cannot be resolved or isn't a field

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've got a ActionBar in my application. I can see it, click on the item etc. But I can't do anything because the program doesn't recognize the item in my `onOptionsItemSelected` function.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.create_playlist:
        // ...
        return true;

        default : return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

The item `create_playlist` gives me this error :

> create_playlist cannot be resolved or is not a field

Yet this item is defined in my actionbar_menu.xml, with this id. Tutorials I've found on the web use the same method and seem to work.
Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: `android.R.id.create_playlist`....Shouldn't that just be `R.id.create_playlist` (without the `android.` prefix)?

Comment: oh Lord ... I definitely need some sleep. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: OK, I created an answer based on my comment. Glad to help.

Comment: Probably picked up android.R.id.home and only changed the suffix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
android.R.id.create_playlist
```

Shouldn't that just be `R.id.create_playlist` (without the `android.` prefix)?